# Abort running method/thread

Tags: c++, qt, c++17

I'm working on software that implements the Westervelt equation in C++17 with QT. (Nonlinear acoustics)

I have a background thread that is running the simulation, and I want the user to be able to abort that thread by clicking on a button.

Here is the code:

```
void DialogArray::on_btn_calculate_clicked()
{
    QString folder = uiArray->text_path->text();
    if  (uiArray->cb_Axial->isChecked() ||uiArray->cb_Lateral->isChecked() ||uiArray->cb_Result->isChecked() ){
        if (folder.isEmpty()){
            QMessageBox::critical(this,"No output selected.","You have to select an output path.",QMessageBox::Ok);
        }else{
            if (enoughCore()){
            createfolder(folder);
            QLabel * label = new QLabel();
            std::thread th1;
            th1 =std::thread(&DialogArray::runSimulation,this,uiArray->cb_Axial->isChecked(),
                            uiArray->cb_Lateral->isChecked(),uiArray->cb_Result->isChecked(),folder,label);
            th1.detach();
            }
        }

    }else{
        QMessageBox::critical(this,"No Output selected.","You have to select at least one output.",QMessageBox::Ok);
    }
}
 
void DialogArray::runSimulation(const bool axial, const bool lateral, const bool result, const QString &folder, QLabel * label)
{
    ArrayTransducer arrayTr(1000,uiArray->doubleSpinBoxCoefficient->value(), uiArray->doubleSpinBoxF->value(),
                            uiArray->doubleSpinBoxP0->value(), uiArray->doubleSpinBoxNbCycles->value(),uiArray->doubleSpinBoxNbElem->value(),
                            uiArray->doubleSpinBoxXWidth->value(),uiArray->doubleSpinBoxYWidth->value(), uiArray->doubleSpinBoxGap->value(),
                            uiArray->doubleSpinBoxFocalLength->value(), uiArray->doubleSpinBoxAngle->value(),uiArray->doubleSpinBoxZmax->value(),
                            uiArray->doubleSpinBoxSoundspeed->value());


    dialogstatus->addSimulation(label);
    label->setText("Array :");
    auto timenow =chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(chrono::system_clock::now());
    label->setText(label->text().append(ctime(&timenow)));
    arrayTr.parAT();
    arrayTr.pattern();
    arrayTr.inputSignal();
    arrayTr.saveParam(folder.toStdString());
    arrayTr.calculate(result,folder.toStdString());  //do the job (take hours)
    if (axial){
        arrayTr.axialProfile(folder.toStdString());
    }
    if (lateral){
        arrayTr.lateralProfile(folder.toStdString());
    }
    dialogstatus->moveSimulationToOver(label);
}
```

`

Dialogstatus is a dialog that display if the simulation is running or is over:

Dialogstatus picture:

[image: Dialogstatus picture]

The goal is to have a `QButton` per simulation to know which simulation needs to be aborted.

```
void DialogStatus::addSimulation(QLabel * newSimulation){
    newSimulation->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);");
    uiStatus->SimulationRunningLayout->addWidget(newSimulation);
}
void DialogStatus::moveSimulationToOver(QLabel * simulation){
    uiStatus->SimulationRunningLayout->removeWidget(simulation);
    simulation->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);");
    uiStatus->SimulationOverLayout->addWidget(simulation);
}
```

Comment: If you use `pthread` instead of `std::thread`, and you work on POSIX, then you can send interrupt signal to a given thread. `std::thread` doesn't support this, since it is supposed to work on non-POSIX systems as well. Otherwise `ArrayTransducer` would have to support interrupts. If it doesn't and you can't modify it, then there's nothing else you can do.

Comment: Do you have access to `ArrayTransducer::calculate` (to be able to check periodically some (atomic) stop flag)?

Comment: @G.Sliepen I don't want to check the parameters, I want to stop the currently running simulation

Comment: @Jarod42 The code of ArrayTransducer::calculate is awful, takes more than 700 lines and I don't understand them.

Comment: Is there a main loop inside of it, so `while (true) {do_complex_stuff();}` -> `while (true) { if(should_stop) { return; /* or throw CancelledException{} */ }
 do_complex_stuff();}`?

Comment: @freakish thanks, I will look after pthread and POSIX.

Comment: @Jarod42 the ArrayTransducer::calculate  :[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/gRfWud5s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::thread` doesn't provide API to be interrupted, you have to do it manually:

You need an `std::atomic<bool> stop;`, setting to `true` from outside the working thread to signal that thread should stop. The working thread should check it regularly and stop executing once value is set.

That check might be combined with the "progress" report of the task, something along:

```
class IProgress
{
public:
    virtual ~IProgress() = default;

    // All those methods would be called from working thread
    // use correct functions to change GUI

    virtual void SetProgressionText(const QString&) = 0;
    // virtual void SetProgressionValue(int) = 0;
    // virtual void SetProgressionRange(int, int) = 0;
    virtual void ThrowIfCanceled() = 0;
};

class QtProgress
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    // ...
    void SetProgressionText(const QString& text) {
        ThrowIfCanceled();
        // As I remember, Qt uses signal, so changes are correctly done in main thread
        progressText->setText(text);
    }
    //void SetProgressionValue(int) override;
    //void SetProgressionRange(int, int) override;
    void ThrowIfCanceled() override { if (stop) throw CancelledException; }

public slot:
    void cancel() {
        stop = true; 
        progressTest->setText("Cancelling...");
    }

private:
    QLabel* progressText /* To initialize */;
    std::atomic<bool> stop{false};
};
```

Change your `void long_task(/*..*/)` to

```
void long_task(IProgress& progress, /*..*/)
{
    progress.setText("start job");
    foo(progress);

    for (auto elem : some_container) {
        progress.setText("handling elem:" + std::to_string(elem));
        bar(elem);
    }

    baz(progress);

    progress.setText("job finished");
}
```

Then each `progress` calls are possible interrupt points.

The call should look like:

```
auto label = new QLabel(/*..*/); // Label associated with the job
auto progress = std::make_shared<QtProgress>(label);

std::thread t([progress](){
    try {
        long_task(*progress/*..*/)
    } catch (const CancelledException&)
        // ... remove label
    }});
t.detach();
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don"t really understand what's my `void long_task(/*..*/)`. Is it `void DialogArray::runSimulation(/*..*/)` or `arrayTr.calculate(/**/); ` inside runsimulation ?

Comment: It is more `DialogArray::runSimulation`, but subtask might also use `progress` parameter.

Comment: When I call `runSimulation(*progress/*..*/)` in my try catch, I have an error : 'this' cannot be implicitly captured in this context. 
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: `[this, progress](){/*..*/}`